# Multiple scrollable subviews/tableviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am working on an ipad app where I need the functionality similar the ipad screen shots in this app:

[TSN: iPad Edition](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/tsn-ipad-edition/id428290993?mt=8&s=143455&ign-mpt=uo=4)

basically where I could scroll through many subviews on one single screen, even some subviews could come on the top of each other and then can be closed.

the first idea which came to mind was to insert multiple subviews in a UIScrollView and then do a simple scroll but how do they scroll on top of each other etc.
[image: see the picture in the middle where it has 2 subviews open and they are scrollable on top of each other]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot seems very similar to CLCascade library. You can find it in github at address: https://github.com/appunite/CLCascade. In the linked image there's a screenshot of the example.

[image]

beware that trunk is not so up to date, take a look at branches to see what fits better your needs.

Comment: thanks trapo - there is nothing in the branches - what did you want me to check?

Comment: go to: https://github.com/appunite/CLCascade/network and drag the graph to reach right end side. There you should see lastest commits (ie more active branches)